# Erro ao integrar documento no inventário V10

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde, tenho uma rotina que cria documentos de venda que já funcionava na v9 e migrei recentemente para a v10.

O problema é que ao fazer o Actualiza e quando tenho artigos com tratamento de séries dá o seguinte erro:

> Erro ao integrar o Documento no Inventário. Unrecognized Guid format.

Eis o código da inserção dos números de série:

```
                For Each dtrow As DataRow In Session("dtNumSerie").Select("IdLinha = '" & idlinha & "'")

                    count = count + 1

                    Dim numeroserie As New BasBENumeroSerie

                    numeroserie.Manual = 1
                    numeroserie.Modulo = "V"
                    numeroserie.NumeroSerie = dtrow("NumSerie")

                    numerosserie.Insere(numeroserie)

                Next
```

Alguém tem uma sugestão do que possa ser?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa tarde, na V10 todos os números de série têm um identificador, falta indicá-lo.

```
numeroserie.ID = "<Guid>"
```

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado!